# the Floodlight install error: Permission denied

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ant

I am following [the Installation Guide](https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/floodlightcontroller/pages/1343544/Installation+Guide#InstallationGuide-EclipseIDE).When i input "sudo ant eclipse" to install Eclipse IDE, there are some errors.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/yxcoder/Public/floodlight# sudo ant eclipse
Buildfile: /home/yxcoder/Public/floodlight/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource tasks.properties. It could not be found.

init:

eclipse:

BUILD FAILED
/home/yxcoder/Public/floodlight/build.xml:354: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/yxcoder/Public/floodlight/setup-eclipse.sh" (in directory "/home/yxcoder/Public/floodlight"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:424)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:438)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:630)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 24 more

Total time: 1 second
```

```xml
   346     <target name="eclipse" depends="init">
    347         <pathconvert property="eclipse-lib">
    348             <map from="${basedir}/" to=""/>
    349             <fileset dir="${lib}">
    350                 <patternset refid="lib"/>
    351                 <patternset refid="lib-test"/>
    352             </fileset>
    353         </pathconvert>
    354         <exec executable="${basedir}/setup-eclipse.sh">
    355             <arg value="${main-class}"/>
    356             <arg value="${eclipse-lib}"/>
    357         </exec>
    358     </target>
```

It's same like the error,"BUILD FAILED",is because Permission denied.

Why the error is Permission denied even if root, and how to resolve it?

The environment :

```
jdk "11.0.5-ea"

ant "1.10.6"

ubuntu "5.3.0-18"
```

Comment: Try running `chmod 777 /home/yxcoder/Public/floodlight/setup-eclipse.sh` first

Comment: @CAustin It's work, thank you